# What's the Rust way of doing what I would have done with inheritance to capture events in cursive?

Tags: oop, inheritance, rust, composition

I'm looking for a practical answer here, I understand Rust approach to OOP, composition over inheritance, writing traits to reuse code and all that jazz.... which is all fine if I had full control of the code and I could have chosen to write everything accordingly, but I'm stuck with the following scenario:

I'm trying to use cursive's [TableView](https://docs.rs/cursive_table_view/0.13.0/cursive_table_view/struct.TableView.html), which implements the [View](https://docs.rs/cursive_core/0.2.2/cursive_core/view/trait.View.html) trait, and therefore its method `on_event`. I want to handle more events that those that come with the `TableView` implementation, but I want everything else, including the events that `TableView` already handles, to remain the same.

Since I've done OOP for the best part of 25 years, the natural thing for me to do is to extend TableView, implement `on_event` and call `super.on_event` where I see fit. This is not possible in Rust, as far as I understand.

I could have my own `MyTable` struct, which contains a `TableView` struct, implement the `View` trait on `MyTable`, and for every method just call the same method in `TableView`. I reject this as the proper solution, it can't be...

What's the closest I can get to OOPs `super` paradigm, or alternative, what is the Rust way of doing this without having to write a lot of useless code that just proxies calls to an inner struct of the type that I'm trying to extend?

Edit: For more detail on exactly what I want to accomplish please check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413581/how-to-process-events-in-cursive-without-implementing-a-view).

Comment: Note that `View` only has one required method, so you don't need "a lot of useless code."

Comment: Hi LF, thanks for your comment. What I mean is that I don't want to have proxy methods for every method that TableView implements, if that makes sense?

Comment: I see.  Can you show more about the context in which you want to use the extended `TableView`?

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can "use" inheritance in languages that allow such a thing, so there's no 1:1 "do this instead of inheritance" solution. Software architecture requires a more complete understanding of the requirements and constraints than what you've provided. For starters, what do you mean by "handle more events that those that come with the TableView implementation"? Cursive is pretty well-designed, so if you take a step back and explain what you're trying to accomplish rather than the solution you wish would work, there's sure to be a good solution.

Comment: Cheers Trentcl. There's a couple of things I'd like to achieve, but didn't want to add to the question because that would probably be a different question on "how do I get this exact thing to work in cursive". But if it's helpful, I'm trying to do things similar to what you get with "on_submit" but pressing other keys. I can go around that with capturing the global events and having information about the selected item in the table somewhere globally, but that's just so ugly that my fingers won't type it. Ideas welcome of course! (more in the next comment)

Comment: I'm also willing to extend the TableView functionality so that I can navigate the cells in the table. The current implementation allows you to select rows and to select columns so that you can order by them. In an OO language like those I'm used to this would be feasible by extending TableView, but here I can't see how to do it without rewriting it. I've actually seen myself sending contributions to a few cursive views already to add stuff, which is awesome since now others will be able to use them, but if I had no access to fork those, I would be stuck having to rewrite.

Comment: IMO? Just ask "how do I get this exact thing to work in cursive". There is no (good) system design apart from the problem it solves and the solution to the specific problem is not likely to generalize to any kind of "inheritance bad, do this instead" principle. With regard to your specific problem, though, what I understand is that `TableView`, despite its name, is an item selector control, not a general purpose view (so even if you could extend from it, it probably doesn't have the plumbing necessary to select and manipulate individual cells). Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: thanks again @trentcl Following your advice I've posted a question that goes more to the point. It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413581/how-to-process-events-in-cursive-without-implementing-a-view)

Comment: "Since I've done OOP for the best part of 25 years, the natural thing for me to do is to extend TableView, implement on_event and call super.on_event where I see fit. [..] I could have my own MyTable struct, which contains a TableView struct, implement the View trait on MyTable, and for every method just call the same method in TableView. I reject this as the proper solution, it can't be..." IMO the former was never good practice, people were just excited they could do it. The latter is _significantly_ clearer to read and doesn't open holes to accidentally forgot to override and cause bugs.

Comment: Thanks @GManNickG. I appreciate your take on not inheriting, you're definitely not alone in your thinking. I am still of the opinion that inheritance is vastly superior in scenarios like this, and that composition should be a design choice and not a language limitation. It wasn't my intention though to start a debate of something that has been debated for decades now. Is your suggestion then that the proper way of doing this is to proxy all of TableView methods and rewrite on_event? If not, would you mind taking a look at the other question I linked and maybe suggest an alternative? Cheers!