# How to process events in cursive without implementing a View

Tags: events, rust, rust-cursive

I am writing an application with a [cursive](https://docs.rs/cursive/0.16.3/cursive/) GUI, and I would like to do certain things when the user presses certain keys. For example, when using a [TableView](https://docs.rs/cursive_table_view/0.13.0/cursive_table_view/struct.TableView.html) I would like to perform different actions when the user has selected a row and presses a key (other than `Enter` which is handled by `TableView` and allows me to implement `on_submit`). Those actions would be parametrised by the selected row, i.e. using the index or some value from the row.

Since I don't have access to `on_event` and there doesn't seem to be an associated callback that I can register with the `TableView`, I can only think about storing some "global" parameters from `on_select` and then register global cursive handlers ala add_global_callback. This would be a big mess very soon, so I'm hoping there's a better way.

I thought I could do the equivalent of extending `TableView` as one would do with inheritance in OOP, but I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396321/rust-inheritance) without much success, and was instead given the smart advice in the comments to just ask for what I want to accomplish instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap your `TableView` in an `OnEventView` and you should be able to trap whatever events you want, and it'll pass through whatever you don't.

```rust
cursive.add_layer(
    OnEventView::new(
        TableView::new( ... )
    ).on_event(...)
```

I saw your other post. My two cents about that :

So instead of the OOP way of extending `TableView` you insert a view "above" `TableView` that does some work. This can be thought of the same as extending, but it's more generic. The `OnEventView` can "wrap" any View, whereas extending a specific class is only useful for that class.
Extending usually means you have to implement a bunch of boilerplate that has nothing to do with traping events, which is all you want to do in this case.